# Multiple Web.config In Asp.net Mvc3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

My project specifications are ASP.net MVC3 Application with Entity Framework.

The problem is that Customer wise the database will be created. Individual application individual database is working fine for me.

But i want a single application and multiple databases should be used with that.

How to achieve the same?

Comment: AFAIU, you cannot resolve it with multiple configs, you need to store the connectionstrings into a seperate Db that shall select appropriate connection while the customer logs in.

Comment: Thanx Fruqan, Can i dynamically write the connection string in web.config?

Comment: Yes you can write the config dynamically but that shall reset the web application and logs out the customer.

Comment: All the customer can be logged in at the same time, then how to manage that condition?

Comment: Thats why writing config is not a good solution, maintain a seperate table for connstr, and when customer logs in, retrieve its connection string and let say put it in his session, and whenever connection string is needed, pass it on from the session. There can be more elegant solutions depending on how yuo wrote you code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your entity connections using the default constructor and web.config-driven connection string, you need to manually build the entity connection string and feed it into it on construction using one of the other constructors.  There's usually one that takes a string, and another that takes an `EntityConnection` instance as well.

If the only thing that changes is the name of the database, then you can probably get away with a format string - where you perhaps take the one that's currently in your web.config - which will look something like this:

`metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=[server];Initial Catalog=[db];User ID=[user];Password=[password]"`

*Note - `[server]`, `[db]`, `[user]` and `[password]` here are placeholders.*

And simply replace the `[db]` with `{0}`.

Then - assuming you can derive a database name from a user you might do something like this following:

```
public string BaseConnectionString {
  get{
    //TODO: Get base connection string - can just bake in the constant string with
    //with the format placeholder.  A better thing would be to add it as an 
    //AppSetting in web.config
  }
}

//this now becomes you're primary way of getting a database connection for a user.
public MyEntities GetEntities(User user)
{
  var eConnectionString = GetConnectionString(user);

  return new MyEntities(eConnectionString);
}

public string GetConnectionString(User user)
{
   var dbName = get_db_name_for_user(user);
   return string.Format(BaseConnectionString, dbName);
}
```

This is but one way to achieve this.  In an IOC environment it would be possible to hide all of this behind a simple `Resolve<>` call.

Comment: Thank you andras the only problem remains is when second customer logs in the first one get logged out automatically. How to deal with that

Comment: Hmmm...  sounds to me like you're using `static` variables somewhere where you shouldn't :)